# Using OnInstalling feature event in Installshield installscript

Tags: events, windows-installer, installshield

I am new to Installshield and having some problems.

My Questions are :

How Can I use OnIstalling Event of a specific feature to reset the progress bar for the installation of this feature (In this feature SQL scripts will be install)?

and

How reset the progress bar for the installation of a feature ( I need to run SQL Scripts and i want the progress bar to be start from 0% when SQL scripts start installing)

kindly help, your answers will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score -1):

In your OnInstalling handler, try these functions:

**SetStatusWindow ( nPercent, szString );**
The SetStatusWindow function sets an initial or current value for the percentage complete indicator of the progress indicator (status bar) and specifies the current message to display on the top line of the progress indicator.

**StatusUpdate ( bLink, nFinalPercent );**
The StatusUpdate function enables or disables the link between file transfer operations and the progress indicator of the status bar. When bLink is ON, the link is enabled and nFinalPercent specifies a final percentage to be displayed at the end of the next file transfer. During that file transfer, the status bar is updated smoothly from its current value to the value specified by nFinalPercent. When bLink is OFF, the link is disabled and the progress indicator of the status bar is not updated automatically during subsequent file transfers.

Comment: hi William Leara thanks for your answer, I want to know a bit more that how can I use OnInstalling event of a specific feature like I want to perform some task on the beginning of installation of a feature then how would use oninstalling event. When I use Oninstalling for which ever feature it performs that action on beginning of whole installation.